# WPF binding on Slider does not update on Maximum change

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

- `combobox1.SelectedItem` is bound to `SelectedItemProperty`.
- The when `SelectedItemProperty` is set, `MaxValueProperty` is calculated
- `MaxValueProperty` is bound to `slider1.Maximum`
- `slider1.Value` is bound to `SliderValueProperty`

These all work fine, except when `combobox1.SelectedItem` changes, and `MaxValueProperty` is calculated, and comes out less than `SliderValueProperty`.

In the View:

- `slider1.Maximum` is updated, because `MaxValueProperty` was changed,
- `slider1.Value` is set to `slider1.Maximum` as default behavior of a slider when the max changes to less than the value.

However, when this happens, `SliderValueProperty` does not get updated to the new `slider1.Value`

```
<Slider Name="slider1" Maximum="{Binding Path=MaxValueProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{Binding Path=SliderValueProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I know that slider1.Value is getting changed, because I have a label bound to it, and the label changes

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource NumberToStringConverter}}" />
```

How can I ensure the binding is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than relying on the default behavior of the slider and a `TwoWay` binding, raise a `PropertyChanged` event after you compute the new maximum in your `SelectedItemProperty` *setter*, first on "SliderValueProperty" using the new maximum, and then second on "MaxValueProperty".  Do your computations on your private backing fields, not on the public properties.

This will cause the system to adjust first the value of the slider, and then the maxvalue, and it should move the slider position for you.

Set the binding mode on slider1's `Maximum` to `OneWay`, as well; I think that will do the trick.

As follows with a viewmodel like this:

```
Class viewmodel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private _selectedItemProperty As ComboBoxItem
Public Property SelectedItemProperty As ComboBoxItem

    Get
        Return _selectedItemProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As ComboBoxItem)
        MaxValueProperty = value.Content
        If _sliderValueProperty > _maxValueProperty Then _sliderValueProperty = _maxValueProperty
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MaxValueProperty"))
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("SliderValueProperty"))
    End Set
End Property
Private _maxValueProperty, _sliderValueProperty as Single
Public Property MaxValueProperty As Single ' with setter that will raise PropertyChanged and use the backing field

'...

Public Property SliderValueProperty As Single ' with a setter that will raise PropertyChanged and use the backing field

'...

End Class
```

And the XAML looks a little like this:

```
    <Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,38,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemProperty}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="50" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="30" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="10" />
    </ComboBox>
    <Slider Name="slider1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,135,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Value="{Binding SliderValueProperty}" Minimum="1" Maximum="{Binding MaxValueProperty}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" Margin="40,174,293,96" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Shortly before you answered, I did a similar if statement to yours, but on the property, and assigning SliderValueProperty raises it's propertychanged event, fixing my problem. One question though - Why do the computations on the private backing fields, then manually raise the property changed event?

Comment: Given the description of your problem it seemed like the most explicit and straightforward way to do it when MVVM is in use. You had a property setter which changed conditions on other properties, and while you can do it the way you chose without problems, I didn't know anything else about your program. I usually choose to be explicit about raising PropertyChanged when I want the changes to appear in the UI.

Comment: yeah it's just the difference between `if(SliderValueProperty > MaxValueProperty){SliderValueProperty = MaxValueProperty; }` and `if(_SliderValueProperty > _MaxValueProperty){_SliderValueProperty = _MaxValueProperty; RaisePropertyChanged(SliderValueProperty);}`